# How can be an open source project released without publishing a few (private) parameters?

Tags: ios, github, parse-platform, open-source, bitbucket

I'd like to release one of my projects (an iPhone app).
The problem I have is that I use Parse, google admob and google analytics, so all of them have private keys or app keys that I have to remove when publish them as open source. But I stil want to continue the development of my app from that repo. 
How can I automate the process of removing that data and at the same time add them when I work with the project? I want to avoid uploading that private data by mistake.
I'd like to know your suggestions or ideas about this topic.
BTW, I prefer to use BiitBucket or GitHub, maybe they have some feature or plugin for that, no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good practice consists in gathering all your private keys in a config file (in the case of your app it would be a header containing several define), and add this config file to the .gitignore of your project. Then in your README simply mention that contributors should create in their workspace this config file with their own private keys.

By doing this you will first have a unique config file, so you know where to look at when you want to update a key, and secondly it will prevent you from publishing it by mistake.